# Как отправить запись звука NAudio в новый поток

Tags: c#, wpf

```
waveIn = new WaveInEvent(); 
waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable; //Прикрепляем к событию DataAvailable обработчик, возникающий при наличии записываемых данных
waveIn.RecordingStopped += waveIn_RecordingStopped; //Прикрепляем обработчик завершения записи
waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1); //Формат wav-файла - принимает параметры - частоту дискретизации и количество каналов(здесь mono) 
waveIn.StartRecording();
```

На просторах сети говорят использовать вместо класса WaveIn() - WaveInEvent()

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313191

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370297

Мол он сам создаст отдельный фоновый поток для обработчика waveIn.DataAvailable

Но у меня в случае начала записи элементы управления окна всё равно остаются недоступными

Если вручную отправлять запись в поток, то вылетает исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём причина и как это исправить?

Comment: Вы неправильно перевели ответы. WaveInEvent не создает фоновой поток - а поддерживает работу в таком потоке.

Comment: The WaveInEvent class should be used in this instance. It will create its own background thread
что тут можно было не так перевести?

Comment: Там продолжение есть. *... and use a SyncContext to marshal callbacks onto the GUI thread if possible* Перевод: обработчик события все равно вызывается в потоке UI.